# Combining estimates from multiple regressions

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I am interested in using quantile regression to fit the following model at different quantiles of a response variable:

(1)  y = b0 + b1*g1 + b2*g2 + B*Z

where b0 is an intercept, g1 and g2 are dummy variables for 2 of 3 independent groups, and Z is a matrix of covariates to be adjusted for in the estimation (e.g., age, gender).  The problem is that estimates for g2 and g1 are not estimable at all quantiles.  To overcome this, one option is to fit a separate model for each group (i.e., group 0, which is reflected by intercept above, group 1, and group 2):

(2)  y = b11 + B1*Z (model for group 0)
(3)  y = b12 + B2*Z (model for group 1)
(4)  y = b13 + B3*Z (model for group 2)

This would correspond to fitting a single model in which group membership was interacted with all covariates, albeit some of the interaction terms would not be estimable for the reason noted above.  However, I ultimately would like to base inferences on a single set of estimates.

Can anyone suggest an approach to combine estimates from models (2)-(4), perhaps through weighted averaging, to generate estimates for the model presented in (1) above?  An approach is not immediately clear to me since the group effects are subsumed in the intercepts in (2)-(4), whereas (1) includes separate estimates of group effects instead of a single weighted average.

Regards,

Jim